# Photon absorption in different layers

Tags: probability, absorption

Let's suppose that space is divided into different regions:

1. for $x < 0$ there is just vacuum space;
2. for $x$ between 0 and $t_1$ space is filled with a material of type 1;
3. for $x$ between $t_1$ and $t_2$ a material of type 2 is present;
4. for $x$ larger than $t_2$ there is vacuum again.

For simplicity let's ignore reflection or other phenomena other than absorption.
How can be expressed the probability density function for the "survival" distance $t$ of a photon incoming from negative infinity along x axis?

Note: The random variable t should be the same as the the point in which the absorption of the photon occurs. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That's often handled as an exponential decay problem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law

Comment: why is the photon moving in the $y$ direction?

Comment: In addition to absorption, one has to take into account reflection at each surface, and reflection of the reflection and so on.  You'll need the refractive index, complex if there is absorption (or equivalently the attenuation coefficient for each material) and then follow the sequences of rays that make it out of the back end taking account of reflection at each surface encountered, and absorption in the layers.  Question:  PDF with respect to what?  Wavelength?

Comment: PDF of the random variable t that represents the distance travelled along x axis until absorption occurs i.e. the distance for which the photon survives or analogously the PDF of the absorption point along x axis. I imagine that this PDF should be 0 for x < t1 and x>t2. For simplicity let's ignore reflection and other phenomena.